# to create dropdown in word add-in using typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ms-word, add-in

I want to create a drop-down in word add-in using angular typescript having options yes and no and on the selection of particular option. I want to add a paragraph in a word document. Can any one suggest a good way.

Comment: I suggest you try it yourself before asking for a solution.

Comment: I tried it. HTML part is    <div>
    <select>
            <option value="choose" >choose option</option>
        <option value="Yes" (click)="yesClicked()">Yes</option>
        <option value="No" >No</option>
        </select>
</div>      and then calling                                                                        function   yesClicked(){
        this.wordDocument.yesclicked();
    }                                     and then  in fuction i had witten code of inserting a paragraph in word document

Comment: Edit the question so it includes the code instead

Comment: thanks for suggesting. I got the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, create a dropdown in HTML

```
<div>
<select class="form-control" (change)="yesClicked($event.target.value)">
    <option value="choose" >choose option</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No" >No</option>
    </select>
```

then add type scripting code

```
   yesClicked(eventName:any){
    if(eventName=='Yes')
        {
            this.wordDocument.yesclicked();
        }
        else if(eventName =='No')
            {

                this.wordDocument.Noclicked();
            }
}
```

then define the function

```
    yesclicked()
    {   
     Word.run(function (context) {
     var body = context.document.body;
     body.insertParagraph('Content of a new paragraph', 
     Word.InsertLocation.end);
      return context.sync().then(function () {
    console.log('Paragraph added at the end of the document body.');
      });  
     })   
     .catch(function (error) {
   console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
  if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
    console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
   }
 });

 }
```